# есть программа на функцию datetime. но выводит ошибку не могу понять в чём причина

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
block_end_timestamp=datetime.now(tz=None)+ 3600
if block_end_timestamp<datetime.now(tz=None):
    print('yee')
```

выводит следующую ошибку:

```
block_end_timestamp=datetime.now(tz=None)+ 3600

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Comment: потому что не получится сложить яблоки и километры. Сколько будет четверг плюс 120?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте для [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

block_end_timestamp = datetime.now(tz=None) + timedelta(seconds=3600)
```

Можно сразу часы указать:

```
block_end_timestamp = datetime.now(tz=None) + timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: почему не показывает Yee если указать (seconds=3)?

Comment: @tailor, т.к. условие неправильное. Вы к текущей дате добавляете время, после проверяете, что текущая дата больше, чем `block_end_timestamp`

Comment: Впрочем, в примере то условие ненужное, поэтому уберу из ответа

Comment: тогда ломается вся программа. как тогда вывести 'yee' через определённое время?

Comment: @gil9red я думаю лучше использовать импорты в том же стиле как в вопросе, чтобы не путать новичков (но это на ваше усмотрение)

Comment: @insolor, ок :)

Comment: @tailor, у вас она и так была сломана :) Сделайте цикл и итерируйте его с задержкой пока не сработает условие или просто сделайте задержку на 1 час. А у вас какая задача? Ждать выполнение кода через N-секунд?

Comment: нет, я мини игру делаю у меня есть бесплатный ящик который можно открывать, но надо что бы его можно было открывать только раз в час для честности

Comment: @gil9red поможете с мини игрой?

Comment: @tailor, понятно :) Лучше оформите проблему с миниигрой отдельным вопросом, т.к. по текущему вопросу проблема решена. Ну и опишите в новом вопросе подробности - консольная ли программа, как вводятся данные и в какой момент проверять. Т.е. это может быть бесконечный цикл с `input()`, вы в нем на первый раз получаете `block_end_timestamp` и при обработке из `input()` проверяете, например, что текущее время больше, чем было `block_end_timestamp`, тогда можно выдать награду, иначе - "время еще не пришло"